# python - not printing additional rows from json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have the below code but for some reason it's only writing the first row for car and ignoring every car after.

edit - I tried putting a `print field` in the row after `for field in required_fields:` and for some reason it only shows the field when parsing the first row.  Every additional row it returns `[]` for each field.

What I see in the csv is the header and one row and then `,,,,`

```
import csv
import json

car_list = [
  {
    "Year": 1997,
    "Make": "Ford",
    "Model": "E350",
    "Description": "ac, abs, moon",
    "Price": 3000
  },
  {
    "Year": 1999,
    "Make": "Chevy",
    "Model": "Venture \"Extended Edition\"",
    "Price": 4900
  },
  {
    "Year": 1999,
    "Model": "Venture \"Extended Edition, Very Large\"",
    "Description": "",
    "Price": 5000
  },
  {
    "Year": 1996,
    "Make": "Jeep",
    "Model": "Grand Cherokee",
    "Description": "MUST SELL!air, moon roof, loaded",
    "Price": 4799
  }
]


def _get_attr(dict_, attrs):
    try:
        src = attrs[:]
        root = attrs.pop(0)
        node = dict_[root]
        null = object()
        for i, attr in enumerate(attrs[:]):
            try:
                node = node.get(attr, null)
            except AttributeError:
                node = null
            if node is null:
                # i+2 pop and last element
                raise ValueError("%s not present (level %s)" % (attr, '->'.join(src[: i+2])))
        return node
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("%s not present" % root)

required_fields = [
    ['Year'],
    ['Make'],
    ['Model'],
    ['Description'],
    ['Price']
]

f = csv.writer(open('test.csv', 'wb+'))

f.writerow(['Year',
           'Make',
           'Model',
           'Description',
           'Price'])

for car in car_list:
    row_values = []
    for field in required_fields:
        try:
            row_values.append(_get_attr(car, field))
        except:
           row_values.append('')
    f.writerow(row_values)
```

Comment: Because `attrs.pop(0)` removes your `field` from `required_fields`. Lists are passed by reference, not value.

Comment: ah ok.  so how do I get it to reset to the initial `required_fields` on each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this occurs is because of a combination of two things:

- Lists (and more generally *mutable* objects) are passed by reference in Python. Mutating a list passed as an argument to a function mutates that list globally.
- You're mutating `attrs` passed in to `_get_attr` by calling `attrs.pop(0)`. This removes the field everywhere, including in `required_fields`.

A much better way to do what you want while using native Python:

```
required_fields = ['Year', 'Make', 'Model','Description','Price']

for car in car_list:
    row_values = [car.get(field, '') for field in required_fields]
    f.writerow(row_values)
```

This immediately takes care of possibly missing values by using the power of [`get()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) on dictionaries to supply a default value - `''` in this case - if a key is missing, and requires no messy `_get_attr` function either.

Comment: I get a traceback when trying this - `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 74, in <module>
    row_values = [car.get(field, '') for field in required_fields]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @whoisearth Edited. There is no need to put your required field names in their own special list. :)

Comment: have to change my required_fields to a straight list.  makes sense.  problem is, if I have a value like ` ['Make']['Sub-Type']`

Comment: @whoisearth Why would that ever arise? Your original data list doesn't contain an example of that instance. All you want to do is iterate through your list of dictionaries and correctly write the values to a file in the right order. This solution accomplishes that.

Comment: this was a sample to figure out why it wasn't carrying through my list.  in my working example my json has a few nested values but it's a long json that can't really be copied.  separate question anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The data in `car_list` is already structured as a list of dictionaries, why not use a `DictWriter` instead of this:

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['Year',
           'Make',
           'Model',
           'Description',
           'Price']
f = csv.DictWriter(open('test.csv', 'wb+'), fieldnames=fieldnames)
f.writeheader()

f.writerows(car_list) # write all rows at once
```

If you're not sure about matching fieldnames in the defined header and `cars_list`, then instead of a single line `writerows`, you can use `writerow` in a loop with `del` to clean up rows before writing them to the csv:

```
for car in car_list:
    for field in car:
        if field not in fieldnames:
             del car[field]
    f.writerow(car)
```

Comment: I can look into this but as shown some fields may not exist and example doesn't show it but the headers will ultimately be different than the key in the json.

Comment: @whoisearth Fields that do not exist are written as blank `''`, like you have in your code

Comment: ah cool going to tinker with this now :)  if it works I'll make completed.